# How to run throttle stop script at startup?

Tags: startup-applications, cpufreq, modprobe

I have tried this ([How do I write a script that runs on startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216765/how-do-i-write-a-script-that-runs-on-startup)) to automatically run a throttle stop script at startup. But I cannot make it work.

I've tried the methods (GUI app, cron job and /rc.local) described here: https://www.fosslinux.com/42796/how-to-auto-execute-linux-startup-scripts-and-commands.htm

And, I have also tried the following tool (https://github.com/agoose77/throttlestop), but it didn't work.

The script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Prevent unset variable problems
set -u

# Change CPU setting
cpufreq-set -c 0 -g performance
cpufreq-set -c 1 -g performance
cpufreq-set -c 2 -g performance
cpufreq-set -c 3 -g performance
modprobe msr
wrmsr 0x1FC 2359388
```

Some info that may help:

- PC: Dell Vostro 15 3568
- cpuinfo: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6100U CPU @ 2.30GHz
- cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
- cpufreq/scaling_governor: powersave
- current frequency: 400 MHz
- linux version: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and server or desktop?

Comment: @David Linux Mint 20 but I'm planning to go back to Ubuntu 20.04, so make it Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=275464

I know is mint related, but Ubuntu users may be benefited from it. Thanks!

Comment: There is only one issue with it. When pc suspends, the script has to be re-executed.