# Override CPU frequency limitation on a MacBook Pro without battery

Tags: kernel, intel, bios, macbook-pro, cpufreq

I have a MacBook Pro late 2013 that has frequency limitation at 800Mhz due to lack of battery.
I'm trying to override this limitation running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

```
$ uname -r
5.15.0-46-generic
```

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  4
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4258U CPU @ 2.40GHz
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               69
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  2
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            1
    Frequency boost:     enabled
    CPU max MHz:         2401,0000
    CPU min MHz:         768,0000
    BogoMIPS:            4800.26
    Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp
                          lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3
                          sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_
                         single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm
                          ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
Virtualization features: 
  Virtualization:        VT-x
Caches (sum of all):     
  L1d:                   64 KiB (2 instances)
  L1i:                   64 KiB (2 instances)
  L2:                    512 KiB (2 instances)
  L3:                    3 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:                    
  NUMA node(s):          1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
Vulnerabilities:         
  Itlb multihit:         KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
  L1tf:                  Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cache flushes, SMT vulnerable
  Mds:                   Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
  Meltdown:              Mitigation; PTI
  Mmio stale data:       Not affected
  Retbleed:              Not affected
  Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Retpolines, IBPB conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP conditional, RSB filling
  Srbds:                 Mitigation; Microcode
  Tsx async abort:       Not affected
```

I've read a lot of documentations like [CPU frequency scaling](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/CPU_frequency_scaling), and others questions and answers like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350453/override-bios-limitation-on-cpu-frequency) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337147/throttlestop-for-ubuntu/1120099#1120099) but any attempt to rise the cpu frequency up didn't work.

**Until now I tried to:**

-Change governor

-Ignore BIOS limitation by adding `intel_pstate=disable processor.ignore_ppc=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

-Set to `1` the value in `/sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc`

-Set the frequency manually (among those available)

-Charge `speedstep_lib` module from available modules (I'm not familiar with linux modules)

**but as you can see:**

```
~$ cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us
  hardware limits: 768 MHz - 2.40 GHz
  available frequency steps:  2.40 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.30 GHz, 2.00 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.30 GHz, 1.10 GHz, 900 MHz, 768 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 768 MHz and 2.40 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 800 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

```
~# i7z
...
Socket [0] - [physical cores=2, logical cores=4, max online cores ever=2]
  TURBO ENABLED on 2 Cores, Hyper Threading ON
  Max Frequency without considering Turbo 2498.96 MHz (99.96 x [25])
  Max TURBO Multiplier (if Enabled) with 1/2/3/4 Cores is  29x/29x/29x/29x
  Real Current Frequency 799.67 MHz [99.96 x 8.00] (Max of below)
        Core [core-id]  :Actual Freq (Mult.)  C0%   Halt(C1)%  C3 %   C6 %  Temp      VCore
        Core 1 [0]:       799.67 (8.00x)     100    66.7       0       0    63      0.6528
        Core 2 [1]:       799.70 (8.00x)     100    66.7       0       0    62      0.6544
...
```

I strongly believe that Linux can overcome these limits.

Is there a way to override this CPU frequency limitation?

Comment: This is not possible in software as the CPU limitation is built into the motherboard (the UEFI specifically). If you want to get the full speed of the machine, you will need to get a replacement battery or wire up a small device like a Raspberry Pi to report itself as a battery and supply expected battery metadata to the MacBook … which is more work than most people are willing to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!